# Get the id of a Textview from inflated layout

Tags: android, layout-inflater

i have a xml like this:

item.xml with the below code:

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="15dip"
    android:paddingBottom="15dip"
    android:paddingLeft="15dip"
    android:textSize="24sp"/>
```

Now i have different setcontentView in my activity, now i am trying to get the id of this textview to set font and color of the textview.

i tried this but not working:

```
View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_title);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: The snippet is corret. What's the issue?

Comment: Its not setting the color of the text

Comment: are you sure that is list_item_title shown at screen?

Comment: R.layout.item.xml should be R.layout.item

Comment: @Raghunandan what are you talking about?

Comment: i thought he had R.layout.item.xml instead of R.layout.item. its irrelevant

Comment: why don't you just set the color of text in xml itself

Comment: @Goofy do you have any text in textview?

Comment: i have manually set the color for different reasons

Comment: @SankarV yes i have it

Comment: @goofy where you added the inflated layout to the Activity's UI?

Comment: @SankarV No its a different layout where i am passing it to a arrayAdapter

Comment: @Goofy As for as I know Nothing wrong with what you have shown to us. I think you might show us the other related code to help you